# Cassandra alpine image release plan?

Tags: docker, cassandra

There is no cassandra alpine image available on Docker Hub.The cassandra image uses debian:stretch-slim as the base image which has vulnerabilities.
Is there any plan to release the alpine version of cassandra with lesser vulnerabilities?

Vulnerability scan of cassandra image through JFrog Xray:
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a topic for SO, rather for the maintainers of the cassandra images.

Answer (score 2):

The awesome thing about Docker is, you can make anything you want yourself! This is a very simplistic build, and I advice you to look at the official Dockerfile and how they set it up. But hopefully this gets you going.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
RUN apk --no-cache update \
    && apk --no-cache add openjdk8-jre

RUN wget http://apache.40b.nl/cassandra/3.11.3/apache-cassandra-3.11.3-bin.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf apache-cassandra-3.11.3-bin.tar.gz \
    && rm -rf apache-cassandra-3.11.3-bin.tar.gz

WORKDIR /apache-cassandra-3.11.3/bin/

# 7000: intra-node communication
# 7001: TLS intra-node communication
# 7199: JMX
# 9042: CQL
# 9160: thrift service
EXPOSE 7000 7001 7199 9042 9160
CMD ["./cassandra", "-R", "-f"]
```

Build it:
`docker build -t alpine-cassandra .`

Run it:
`docker run alpine-cassandra`

Comment: Thanks but you forgot to mount a volume to persist data